# Getting the id of the first row in tbody with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have some HTML like this:

```
 <tbody id="box_id">
        @foreach($documents as $document)
        <tr id="row_{{$document->id}}">
         ...
       </tr>
      @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

And some Jquery like this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {

    case 38: // up

            var row = $('#box_id').find('tbody tr:first').attr('id');
            alert(row);



        break;
           ...
```

I want to get the id of the first row in the tbody when I press up. It keeps alerting `undefined`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use it as `$('#box_id').find('tr:first').attr('id')` as `box_id` is the id of `tbody` itself.

Comment: @PrashantShirke Yep that is. You might want to write it in the answers so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it as `$('#box_id').find('tr:first').attr('id')` as `box_id` is the id of `tbody` itself.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code you are finding  `tbody tr` inside `tbody`..
Just update your code with following..

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    switch(e.which) {
    case 38: // up
        var row = $('#box_id').find('tr:first').attr('id');
        alert(row);
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already in the tbody, so you will not find an other tbody. Please try the following code:

```
$('#box_id').find('tr:first').attr('id');
```

... or even better:

```
$('#box_id > tr:first').attr('id');
```